# Regex to check remove characters other than alphabets

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I need a regular expression that checks for the DebugData, and if it has any digits or special characters other than alphabets[a-zA-Z], replace those special characters with spaces. The tables are present in Google Big Query and I am querying it using IPython notebooks.

Example: When DebugData is Movist2, then ActualCarrier should be Movist, and when DebugData is LAO GS2, then ActualCarrier should be LAOGS2 and when DebugData is CLARO"3, then ActualCarrier is CLARO.

```
SELECT 
Id, e.Carrier as AssignedCarrier, 
CASE
 WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'jasp%' THEN 'Jasper' 
 WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'telu%' THEN 'Telus'
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(DebugData,'\\w+\\d+') THEN DebugData
 WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(lower(DebugData),'\\d+') THEN c.Network
END
AS ActualCarrier
FROM debug_table
```

This is the statement I added:

```
ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(DebugData),'\\[^a-zA-Z]',' ')
```

Still I get this output:

```
HardwareId  DebugData   ActualCarrier   count
550466188   CLARO"3      None            5
```

Comment: This is google big query. However, I am not sure about the regex for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
  DebugData, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData, r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ') as ActualCarrier 
FROM
  (SELECT'Movist2' as DebugData),
  (SELECT'LAO GS2' as DebugData),
  (SELECT'CLARO"3' as DebugData)
```

Added to address additional comment / question

```
SELECT
  DebugData, 
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(LOWER(DebugData),r'^\d+$') THEN Network 
    ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(DebugData),r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ') 
  END AS ActualCarrier
FROM
  (SELECT'123' AS DebugData, 'aaa' AS Network),
  (SELECT'Movist2' AS DebugData, 'bbb' AS Network),
  (SELECT'456' AS DebugData, 'ccc' AS Network),
  (SELECT'LAO GS2' AS DebugData, 'ddd' AS Network),
  (SELECT'CLARO"3' AS DebugData, 'eee' AS Network),
  (SELECT'Test' AS DebugData, 'fff' AS Network)
```

Comment: I have these two statements in my query:

WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(lower(DebugData),'\\d+') THEN c.Network

ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(DebugData),r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')

When DebugData contains only digits, then it should take the c.Network but for a combination of digits and alphabets, it should replace the other characters and print only alphabets.

For eg., DebugData - 123768, then ActualCarrier should refer to c.Network, when DebugData is 'comp2', then ActualCarrier should be 'comp'.

Comment: I believe my first when statement checks for any digit, not for 'only digits'.

Comment: @ Mikhail Berlyant: tried that regex but it throws the error  "Invalid sql; $ with no following $ or identifier: SELECT"

Comment: have you tried my example first as it is? or you modified it? as I just run it and it does work! can you try again and clarify!?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in IPython notebook, it threw that error. When i tried it in GBQ, it runs but it does not provide the desired result. What I tried was

      SELECT
      DebugData, 
      CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(LOWER(DebugData),r'^\d+$') THEN Network 
        ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(LOWER(DebugData),r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ') 
      END AS ActualCarrier   
      FROM
          (SELECT'310220?' AS DebugData, 'aaa' AS Network)

Comment: `1.` looks like your original question is answered and you accepted it! `2.` if you think my answer anyhow contributed - you can vote on it. `3.` if you have any "folow-up" or new questions  - just post them as new question(s) - format of comments does not allow to go further here

Comment: Its because DebugData contains data such as 310410?, 23430"?. It starts with digits followed by some special characters. So in the sub-query, I remove it and do some processing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData, r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#advanced-examples_12

Comment: I tried it, it didnot work. I have edited my question with new line added and the result.

Comment: @user3447653 Is `c.Network` null/none? I don't think it's going to reach the `else`. Perhaps you just need to reorder the cases. I recommend testing this separately since that wasn't ready the question you asked.